# Unable to call dot MVC controller action method from angular service

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, dot

Issue: showing the below Error:
**blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.**

Note: The action method is successfully called using ajax and other web application but angular service call raising an error.

1. angular service call:

`this.http.post("http://localhost:52971/Home/MyLoginController",logindata);`

2. controller action method:

```cs
[HttpPost]

  public JsonResult MyLoginController(Myclass logindata)

  {
    
 bool isAdmin = false;


     string output = isAdmin ? "Welcome to the Admin User" : "Welcome to the specified user";

     return Json(output, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

I have did the following changes in web config but still unable to resolve the issue

```
 <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
        <clear />        
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" /> 
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="X-AspNet-Version,X-Powered-By,Date,Server,Accept,Accept-Encoding,Accept-Language,Cache-Control,Connection,Content-Length,Content-Type,Host,Origin,Pragma,Referer,User-Agent" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1000" />
 
    </customHeaders>
 </httpProtocol>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <verbs allowUnlisted="false">
            <add verb="GET" allowed="true" />
            <add verb="POST" allowed="true" />
            <add verb="DELETE" allowed="true" />
            <add verb="PUT" allowed="true" />
        </verbs>
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Need help,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

CORS uses an OPTIONS request to test the access policy. Try putting
`<add verb="OPTIONS" allowed="true" />`
in your request filtering verbs